# importing an object with extension md2 in libgdx

Tags: java, eclipse, libgdx

i'm  new in java game programing i want to import an md2 object i used this tuto http://code.google.com/p/libgdx-users/wiki/MD2_Keyframe_Animation
but the probleme is that i cant instanciate an instance from class KeyframedModelViewer this is my code

```
package com.ELISA.ELISAgame.Screens;
import com.ELISA.ELISAgame.ELISA;
import com.badlogic.gdx.ApplicationListener;
import com.badlogic.gdx.Gdx;
import com.badlogic.gdx.Screen;
import com.badlogic.gdx.assets.AssetManager;
import com.badlogic.gdx.assets.loaders.ModelLoader;
import com.badlogic.gdx.graphics.GL20;
import com.badlogic.gdx.graphics.PerspectiveCamera;
import com.badlogic.gdx.graphics.g3d.Material;
import com.badlogic.gdx.graphics.g3d.Model;
import com.badlogic.gdx.graphics.g3d.ModelBatch;
import com.badlogic.gdx.graphics.g3d.ModelInstance;
/*import com.badlogic.gdx.graphics.g3d.attributes.TextureAttribute;*/
import com.badlogic.gdx.graphics.g3d.loader.ObjLoader;
import com.badlogic.gdx.graphics.g3d.utils.CameraInputController;


public class Game implements ApplicationListener, Screen {


ELISA game;
PerspectiveCamera cam;
CameraInputController camController;
ModelBatch modelBatch;
ModelLoader loader;
AssetManager assets;
Model model;
Material material;
ModelInstance instance;

public Game(ELISA game) {
    this.game = game;


}

public void create() {


}

@Override
public void render(float delta) {
    camController.update();
    Gdx.gl.glViewport(0, 0, Gdx.graphics.getWidth(),
            Gdx.graphics.getHeight());
    Gdx.gl.glClear(GL20.GL_COLOR_BUFFER_BIT | GL20.GL_DEPTH_BUFFER_BIT);
    modelBatch.begin(cam);
    modelBatch.render(instance);

    modelBatch.end();

}

@Override
public void resize(int width, int height) {


}

@Override
public void show() {

    //new JoglApplication(new KeyframedModelViewer("data/antigene.md2", "data/antigene.png"), "KeframedModel Viewer", 800, 480, false);
    modelBatch = new ModelBatch();
    cam = new PerspectiveCamera(67, Gdx.graphics.getWidth(),Gdx.graphics.getHeight());
    cam.position.set(0f, 6f, 11.5f);
    cam.lookAt(0, 0, 0);
    cam.near = 0.8f;
    cam.far = 300f;
    cam.update();

    loader = new ObjLoader();
     //model = loader.loadModel(Gdx.files.internal("data/labo.obj"));
     instance = new ModelInstance(model);
     Material material = new Material("material", new TextureAttribute(texture, 0, "s_tex"));
     model.setMaterial(material);
    camController = new CameraInputController(cam);
    Gdx.input.setInputProcessor(camController);

}

@Override
public void hide() {


}

@Override
public void pause() {


}

@Override
public void resume() {


}

@Override
public void dispose() {
    modelBatch.dispose();
    model.dispose();


}
```

}

Answer (score 0):

That wiki, "libgdx-users" is highly outdated. MD2 is not supported right now, this is how 3d animations are handled now:

https://github.com/libgdx/libgdx/wiki/3D-animations-and-skinning

"When using fbx-conv https://github.com/libgdx/fbx-conv to convert your model from FBX to G3DB/G3DJ, animations are automatically converted along with it. Just like FBX, G3DB/G3DJ files can contain multiple animations in a single file along with the other model data. Animations applied to nodes which are not present in the source FBX file, will not be converted. So make sure to select all the nodes and animations when exporting to FBX."

Comment: thank you Lestat i have changed my framework to Jmonkey, i found that there is a lot of problems in libgdx.
my greeting;